# Список городов для сайта

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Поделитесь опытом разработки пожалуйста. Нужно вывести на выбор список городов России на сайте, потом это значение отправить контроллеру. Как это можно сделать без бд?

Answer (score 1):

Есть много сервисов, где по IP определяют местоположения пользователя например [этот](http://ip-api.com/) или [этот](https://freegeoip.net/). Города сохраняешь (можешь добавлять только строго RU) в сессию + каждый раз накапливаешь когда заходят клиенты. Потом когда надо отправляешь в контроллер.

Comment: мне необходимо выбрать город для интернет магазина. Хотел без создания бд это сделать, может скрипты какие есть.